# ERROR boto3 Batch "Waiter does not exist"

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-batch

I have a program that runs a batch of AWS batch tasks, the problem is that the program needs to wait for the jobs to finish to process the responses, for that I understand that I need to use the `get_waiter` function and an array with the ids of the jobs. this is the code I use to executed.

```py
batch = boto3.client('batch')
waiter = batch.get_waiter('job_execution_complete')# Waiter does not exist: job_execution_complete
waiter.wait(jobs=job_ids)
```

when I run it I get this error, I look in the doc but it doesn't show what I'm supposed to do.

> Waiter does not exist: job_execution_complete

### summary

In short, I need to pause the program execution while the AWS batch tasks are running and continue the program process when the tasks are finished.
doc to get_waiter: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/get_waiter.html

Comment: Notice how the EC2 client lists the available waiters at the bottom of the page: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html The Batch client doesn't list any waiters at all, which implies the batch client doesn't actually support any waiters. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html